# Running PHP workers on AppFog

Tags: php, cron, background-process, worker, appfog

I searched and searched and searched but didn't find any resources on that.

**Is there any way to run a *worker* in a PHP app on AppFog?**

I've only found instructions for running Ruby, Node.js and Python workers, based on frameworks of that languages.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After a lot of tinkering myself, I've found a way!

In your php script, you should set timeout limit to `0`, and have a infinite loop, like that:

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);

    while (true) {
        print "blah\n";
        sleep(120);
    }
```

This code will print out "blah" every 2 minutes.

To deploy this to AppFog, you *must* use the `af` console command. The big thing here is to say **no** when it asks if that's a PHP app.

### The steps

1. `af push` on the directory
2. say **no** if it guesses the language of your app
3. Select **Standalone** as the app type.
4. Now you select PHP
5. Enter `php index.php` or whatever name you gave to your application main file.

It's all shown below:

```
D:\Users\Leonel\dev\app>af push
Would you like to deploy from the current directory? [Yn]:
Application Name: APP
Detected a PHP Application, is this correct? [Yn]: n
[...]
6: Standalone
[...]
Select Application Type: 6
Selected Standalone Application
[...]
5: php
[...]
Select Runtime: 5
Selected php
Start Command: php index.php
1: AWS US East - Virginia
[...]
Select Infrastructure: 1
Application Deployed URL [None]:
Memory reservation (128M, 256M, 512M, 1G, 2G) [128M]:
How many instances? [1]:
Bind existing services to 'APP'? [yN]:
Create services to bind to 'APP'? [yN]:
Would you like to save this configuration? [yN]:
Creating Application: OK
Uploading Application:
  Checking for available resources: OK
  Packing application: OK
  Uploading (0K): OK
Push Status: OK
Staging Application 'APP': OK
Starting Application 'APP': OK

D:\Users\Leonel\dev\APP>af logs APP
====> /logs/stdout.log <====

blah
blah
```

### Some Notes

- You need to create a *separate* app to perform the background tasks, though this app can be binded to the same services (e.g databases) of the other apps or this app can `curl` to your other app, for example. Just make sure it's on the same availability zone.
- `af logs APP` will give you the output of the worker, so you can debug and check if everything is ok.

That's it, hope it helps.

Comment: +1 great answer. You might want to wrap it in a try catch and log the errors too.

Comment: can we 'exec' scripts on AppFog in order to simulate parallel processes?

Answer (score 1):

Great solution. I'm unable comment due to insufficient reputation, so I'm modifying the original answer.

To enable the PHP pseudo crontab to start at a specified second, use an enforcement loop at the start of the script, as follows:

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);

    // begin process at zero (00) second mark
    $cnt=0;
    while (true) {
      usleep(250000); // avoid excess looping
      if ( date('s',time()) == '00' ) {
        break;
      }
      if ( $cnt++ > 240 ) {
        break; // something has gone wrong...
      }
    }
    var_dump(date('s',time()));exit; // test/validate

    while (true) {
        print "blah\n";
        sleep(120);
    }
```